# AWS Cognito User authentication flow need suggestions and advices

Tags: amazon-web-services, authentication, amazon-cognito

I am trying to setup mobile application authentication system on AWS using its user pool service.

Since it's mobile only application I need only OTP / MFA confirmation option like whatsapp and here I encountered with my first challenge.

User Pool need username and password compulsorily, since I was using its inbuilt MFA, I used phone_number attribute. I did not need any username or password. Here's what I planned.

1. Allow unauthenticated identities in my cognito credential provider.
2. Processed registration [username = identity provided by cognito, password = "somethingxyz" (yes, hardcoded in s/w), phone_number = provided phone number]
3. After successfully registering with otp passed my IdToken to credential provider & assign the userpool user with the identity created at the beginning.

My concerns are, using hardcoded password is okay in case MFA is mandatory for finishing login process? Is it possible to assign user pool account to unauthenticated identities and turn it authenticated (why? because I used that identity as username in signup process and I don't want some other identity as for that userpool account, while trying this I got multiple random errors though)?

Comment: hi man. did u get it to work. My app also features login based on OTP verified mobile number and since i cant give the username blank, i used the mobile number for the username too.

Comment: I use mobile number along with country code and strip + out of it, so username is pretty easy to build anything user choses country and provides his mobile number. E.g. +919699XXX02 to username : 9196999XXX02

Comment: Have you managed to make this work? : )

Answer (score 4):

I guess stackoverflow doesn't want suggestions or advice, so I will try to format the answer as an answer to the question I think you are asking, which is "What are the roles in the Cognito system and how to I implement my app with them". (This is a question I have been trying to answer for myself for a month or more). My answer is described in terms of the IOS SDK API but would apply generally.

Cognito Identity will issue you "IdentityId's", but does not manage authentication of those identities with username or password etc.

So if you want to have any restrictions or controls on activities, you would need some sort of registration process.  This can use Facebook Identities, Google+ identities or your own identities (called BYOI bring your own identities) or the new Cognito User Pools ( an Identity Provider served by AWS).  (All of these "Identity Providers" provide some sort of Token and a Identity Provider Name behind the scenes). None of these provide IdentityId's, that's Cognito Identity's job.

Cognito Credentials Provider connects a CognitoIdentity IdentityId to an IAM role in AWS so that you can temporarily get AWS Credentials for an IdentityId, and use S3, Lambda, DynamoDb etc.

So using no Username and Password, means that you don't have any authentication, but you can still have Identities, Cognito Identity will maintain them and they will be unique (following the mobile device).  But a user would not be able to move to another device and keep the same identity because he/she would have no way to tell Cognito about his/her identity. That's what Identity Providers do (and they check that you are not lying by asking for password/mfa etc.).

The naming of the API and SDK is pretty difficult to understand, but basically classes starting with CognitoIdentity without the word Provider means the component is part of the Federated Identity system and classes starting with CognitoIdentityProvider is a thing that authenticates that a device/user is who/what it says it is.  And a CognitoIdentityProviderManager returns a CognitoIdentityProvider name (like "graph.facebook.com" or cognito-idp.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/) and a Token (and OpenID Connect token(OIDC)) to let the CognitoIdentity system know that that user is logged in (it does this by returning a logins dictionary of [name:token] to CognitoIdentity. Cognito behind the scenes validates this token with the Open Id connect server or other server (I.E. facebook).

So the question for you is, how are you going to uniquely identify your users (I don't know whatsapp).